# How to get location coordinates in macOS、swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I need to get the geographical coordinates on Mac OS. Here is my code, but an error is reported when running: domain = kclerrordomain code = 0 "(null)"

```
import Cocoa
import CoreLocation

    let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //设置定位服务管理器代理
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //设置定位进度
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest //最佳定位
        //更新距离
//        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        //发出授权请求
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
            //允许使用定位服务的话，开始定位服务更新

//            print("定位开始")

        }
    }

extension ViewController:CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //获取最新的坐标
        let currLocation : CLLocation = locations.last!  // 持续更新
        print("纬度:\(currLocation.coordinate.latitude) 纬度:\(currLocation.coordinate.longitude) 海拔:\(currLocation.altitude) 水平精度:\(currLocation.horizontalAccuracy) 垂直精度:\(currLocation.verticalAccuracy) 方向:\(currLocation.course) 速度:\(currLocation.speed)")
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("location manager auth status changed to:" )
        switch status {
            case .restricted:
                print("status restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("status denied")

            case .authorized:
                print("已授权")
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            case .notDetermined:
                print("status not yet determined")

            default:
                print("unknown state: \(status)")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                            didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print( "location manager failed with error \(error)" )
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJ2E.png)

When running application:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOyll.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add location usage description in your `info.plist` file. After adding your info.plist should look like this [image: <code>info.plist</code>].

Add this line in `viewDidLoad`.

```
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Then add the delegate method that updates the location.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations.last?.coordinate)
}
```